# TinyMCE content blank on MVC Post Action

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, tinymce

I have a standard form with a textbox with tinymce invoked. All is well however when I post to my action the FormCollection for that field is blank. I have set ValidateInput to false just in case but still blank. I believe the issue is because I am posting using the jQuery Form plugin.

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to tell the TinyMCE editor to save the contents back to the textarea before post.

```
 $('#btnSave').click( function(){
        tinyMCE.triggerSave(true,true);
        $('#myform').submit();
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

The triggerSave solution will work. I encountered this same problem when testing TinyMCE 4.2.5, and discovered that omitting the "name" attribute from the textarea control targeted by TinyMCE will also cause it to fail (i.e. a null value gets posted to the controller).  Just adding a "name" attribute to the textarea control fixed it, without applying the triggerSave script.

So the textarea went from this:

```
<textarea id="mceText"></textarea>
```

To this, without employing the triggerSave() function:

```
<textarea id="mceText" name="mceText"></textarea>
```

Maybe this will help someone in the future.  Thanks.

Comment: This should be the preferred solution in my opinion. Adding a "name" property to the textarea solved my issue as well (controller with null text value). No triggers or javascript needed at all.

Answer (score 0):

I solved with a workaround

put the content of the tinymce in a hidden field

```
var loquesea= tinyMCE.get('mytiny').getContent();

$("#fieldHidden").val(loquesea);
```

in the controller is necessary to write `<ValidateInput(False)>`
because the controller receive html characters

`<ValidateInput(False)>`

```
Function saveItem(ByVal KeysCollections As FormCollection) As ActionResult

 Dim ID As String = KeysCollections("fieldHidden")

End Function
```